# In C how to define all unknow macros(used in source file/ header file) in command line

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros

My requirement is to get list of all Header files included in Header file recursively, i am using, as an example on stdio.h

$ gcc -H stdio.h

which fits me, as you know there are #define's which make conditional inclusion of some other Header files based on Macors, now i want such #define's to be passed in the command line, something like

$ gcc -D* -H stdio.h

which automatically defines all the macro's used in the Header file. I tried, but couldn't succeed, any Idea, Thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem i am trying to solve is quite descriptive in my question, for which i got the answer from Mats Petersson.

Comment: For some reasons i cannot disclose the purpose of this requirement. It's not for some compilation of binaries, it's about going deep into OS.

Comment: I am not worried of down vote to my question, but due to some reason, like i said before i cannot tell like **why i want such solution**, but you you read in between lines you would get like what is the solution i am looking for. One more thing, many innovations comes from some weird requirements and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, and it also doesn't make any sense to define ALL macros used by a particular headerfile. Some of those may well be mutually exclusive.

Say for example you have:

```
 #if ARCH_X86
     ... stuff goes here for x86... 
 #endif
 #if ARCH_ARM 
     .... stuff goes here for ARM ... 
 #endif
```

the original author CERTAINLY didn't want you to compile this with both ARM and X86 enabled at the same time, since that combination doesn't make any sense at all.

And even if you were to define ALL defines, you wouldn't catch the second part of this:

```
#if ARCH_X86
   #include <x86_stuff.h>
#else
   #include <arm_stuff.h>
#endif
```

If your project has special defines, then use those. But all defines doesn't make any sense.

A further problem is that you may find system-dependent files, and defines related to those, e.g:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <windows.h>
#elsif LINUX
    #include <linux.h>
#else
    #error "Must be either Linux or Windows". 
#endif

#if WINDOWS_THINGY_BOB
   ... do stuff here ... 
#endif
```

(Assuming WINDOWS_THINGY_BOB is a define set by including windows.h)

Another potential problem is that not everything is "#ifdef", but something like this:

```
#if DEBUG==2
   #include <debug_lots.h>
#elsif DEBUG != 1
   #include <debug_little.h>
#else
   #include <no_debug.h>
#endif
```

If you REALLY want to see "if X is defined, then this is included", you'll have to write your own code to follow the different paths with different defines, including "not set".

I can see that this would get VERY complicated very quickly if you don't have a clear set of "what is my environment that I'm compiling in".

Comment: Hi, i know what you mean and i agree, in fact i knew this before you could tell, but my requirement is quite different, not as for some other mundane projects, was thinking is there is some way to get around this, if someone has already done/ available with gcc(partly like -undef), anyway thanks for confirming that such thing is not available

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but in my experience, you are almost certainly "barking up the wrong tree". I edited my answer to cover some further "this will be weird". If you look at the standard header files for say glibc, you will find that there are LOTS of different defines, which may or may not apply to a particular environment, system, architecture, etc. In other words, "setting everything" is not going to work at all well. You need to understand what will and won't be set in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to parse header files and pass the `#define`-s to the compiler. There is a `-D <name>` option which can be used to define preprocessor names. See here for details: [3.11 Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

One option is to create a makefile and define the [CFLAGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS) variable with the flags that you want to pass to the compiler.